# ROS2 components tutorial fails to launch

Tags: ros2, docker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Composition/

I tried to follow the composition tutorial for ROS2 using the official docker images but it fails to load even the sample components. Is this a bug or did I mess something up?

**Terminal #1:**

```
$ docker run --name fox --rm -it osrf/ros:foxy-desktop
root@a32781ba07af:/# ros2 run rclcpp_components component_container
[INFO] [1607722128.302447462] [ComponentManager]: Load Library: /opt/ros/foxy/lib/libtalker_component.so
[ERROR] [1607722128.303362581] [ComponentManager]: Failed to load library: Could not load library LoadLibrary error: libconsole_bridge.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory, at /tmp/binarydeb/ros-foxy-rcutils-1.0.1/src/shared_library.c:68
```

**Terminal #2:**

```
$ docker exec -it fox /ros_entrypoint.sh bash
root@a32781ba07af:/# ros2 component list
/ComponentManager
root@a32781ba07af:/# ros2 component load /ComponentManager composition composition::Talker
Failed to load component: Failed to load library: could not load library loadlibrary error: libconsole_bridge.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory, at /tmp/binarydeb/ros-foxy-rcutils-1.0.1/src/shared_library.c:68
root@a32781ba07af:/# ros2 component types
<SNIP>
composition
  composition::Talker
  composition::Listener
  composition::NodeLikeListener
  composition::Server
  composition::Client
<SNIP>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/367557/ros2-components-tutorial-fails-to-launch/) by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1070 on 2020-12-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using osrf/ros2:nightly-rmw works as expected.

It looks like ros:foxy-desktop has not been updated in a few months. Is this a bug and if so, where should it be reported.

---

Originally posted by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) with karma: 1070 on 2020-12-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ruffsl](https://answers.ros.org/users/5234/ruffsl/) on 2020-12-15**:
You can report it here:
https://github.com/osrf/docker_images

The osrf/ros repo still isn't as automated as the official library/ros image builds, given DockerHub deprecated triggering automated builds from official library images a year or so ago.
https://github.com/osrf/docker_images/issues/362

I'd recommend using the official repo for most uptodate images:
https://hub.docker.com/_/ros